# uploading a python site to httpdocs?

Tags: python, ftp, cherrypy

OK - so we've agreed to host a python site, got the files and not sure where to go next.

We use a dedicated server and manage it mainly with plesk which has a tick box for a python support but not sure what this does.

---

This is all the info i have from previous hosts;

## 10,000 ft overview

The site is intended to run on a Linux host, specifically Ubuntu Server (tho it should be fine on most distros).

The web framework is CherryPy ( http://cherrypy.org/ ), which is a Python based framework.

There is no database as such, instead the data is kept in JS files and loaded by the front end.
nicholasbarker.com.c6a4facf0192/www/js/video_content_items.js is a prime example of this.

The main site templates are in nicholasbarker.com.c6a4facf0192/www/templates/
They are Cheetah templates ( http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/ )

---

and here's the file structure i've been sent -

[image: and here's the file structure i've been sent]

Could some explain to me how i'd go about uploading and running this site... Any help welcome! Dc

Comment: "...and i have no idea what i'm doing...", wrong words, a high percentage of SO users (like me) will ignore the whole question just because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Plesk supports Python through mod_python in Apache.

However, CherryPy is a web server itself, but can also be called through mod_WSGI in Apache. That is beyond Plesk's built-in capabilities. You'll need to install that module and pray that Plesk doesn't sit in a corner and pout. Oh, and I can come very close to offering a guarantee that Plesk will stomp all over anything you do during its next update.

As for Cheetah Templates, you'll need to download the installation files and run the installation script on your host. Once again, Plesk will likely become irrationally jealous, set your house on fire and sue for alimony.

Next, you will have to replicate the client's file structure onto the Plesk account that you set up for your client. The file structure involves more than just the httpdocs folder, so you'll want to be selective in what you move over. Also, I hope that no undocumented environmental variables are needed, but you'll find that out as you go.

I'm not **intentionally** trying to be an unhelpful harbinger of doom. However, I see several strikes against you. One being Plesk itself (be afraid), the other being your admitted lack of experience (be very afraid). You have a tough road ahead of you, and your question simply cannot be answered in one fell swoop.

I recommend eating this elephant one bite at a time. Start with the smallest steps possible, starting with understanding the CherryPy framework and how to set it up. Use Google extensively, and then user ServerFault and other StackExchange sites like they were designed to be used: asking tightly scoped questions for specific problems. We're here to help, even if that means... being harbingers of doom. =)

Comment: thanks wesley! It doesn't sound like an ideal setup at all. And as you say with my lack of experience with python it may be disastrous for all our other clients on our server. I think i'll have to pass this site on. Best, dan.